# Conway-Maxwell Poisson model in pymc3 with confusing data parameters

Tags: python, pymc3

I'm looking at a gist from somebody who has implemented the CMPoisson model in pymc3. Unfortunately there's two steps that I'm not certain about. in the main building of the model.

(gist can be found here: https://gist.github.com/dadaromeo/33e581d9e3bcbad83531b4a91a87509f)

1. In the building of the test data he uses a two step process to calculate the data:

   ```
   n,d = 1000, 4
   X = np.abs(np.random.randn(n,d))
   y = np.round(X.sum(axis=1)).astype(int)
   ```

I'm trying to work out why the two step process is used? is it to create data that is similar to Poisson but has the characteristics of the CMPoisson distribution?

2. In the pymc3 model, the parameters are calculated using the X array:

   ```
   with cmp_model:
       alpha = pm.Normal("alpha", mu=1)
       beta = pm.Normal("beta", mu=1, shape=d)
       lam = alpha + tt.dot(X,beta)
       nu = pm.HalfNormal("nu", sd=10)

       like = CMPoisson("like", lamda=lam, nu=nu, observed=y)
   ```

Why is that? As I'm using real data (that looks like y) I'm not sure where my corresponding X value comes from?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are right about the first step. He is just generating synthetic data for his problem. About the second step, he is doing a CMPoisson regression, i.e. like a "regular" linear regression but the likelihood is not a Gaussian distribution.

I think you do not have any X. If that's the case, then your model should look like:

```
with cmp_model:
    lam = pm.HalfNormal("lam", sd=10)
    nu = pm.HalfNormal("nu", sd=10)

    like = CMPoisson("like", lamda=lam, nu=nu, observed=y)
```

I am not familiar with the Conway-maxwell distribution, but it seems it is used to model over-dispersed data that does not fix well a Poisson distribution. In case you find it useful, PyMC3 has the negative-binomial distribution that is also used to model overdispersed count data.